# What does datatable.columns().search().draw() requests or posts in server-side php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var taskList = $("#tasklist").DataTable({
      "bProcessing" : true,
      "bServerSide" : true,
      "sAjaxSource" : 'response.php'
    });
    $(".search-select").on('change', function() {
      var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
      var f = $(this).val();
      taskList.columns(i).search(f).draw();
    });

    $(".search-text").on('keyup', function() {
      var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
      var f = $(this).val();
      taskList.columns(i).search(f).draw();
    });


  });
```

this is the script i have written and except filtering everything is working. 
I don't know in which variable or object I can get the searched row and value.
I have tried : $_REQUEST['columns'][0]['search']['value']
but it is not in the $_REQUEST object. 
What should I try now?

Comment: is `dataTable` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I have just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Chrome / FF or other browsers developer tools, go to the Network tab and inspect the requests! It could not be more easy. You will see something like

```
response.php
  ?sEcho=1
  &iColumns=6
  &sColumns=%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C
  &iDisplayStart=0
  &iDisplayLength=10
//>> this section repeats itself for every column, mDataProp_1, mDataProp_2 etc
  &mDataProp_0=0
  &sSearch_0=
  &bRegex_0=false
  &bSearchable_0=true
  &bSortable_0=true
//<<<
  &sSearch=
  &bRegex=false
  &iSortCol_0=0
  &sSortDir_0=asc
  &iSortingCols=1
  &_=1513773711430
```

So you get the search term for a `columns(i).search(f).draw()` serverside by

```
$columnCount = $_GET['iColumns'];
$searchColumn = -1;
$searchTerm = '';
for ($i=0; $<$columnCount; $i++) {
  if (isset($_GET['sSearch_'.$i]) && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '') {
    $searchColumn = $i; //i
    $searchTerm = $_GET['sSearch_'.$i]; //f
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$searchValue = $_REQUEST['search']['value']
```

Comment: Undefined index: search in C:\xampp\htdocs\reports\response.php on line 9 that's the error.

Comment: See the browser's network log and check that how your data is going to server

Comment: Yes, it is. If I print_r($_REQUEST) , I can find other variable for datatables but there is nothing that suggests the search value.

Comment: If you send search text then you will get it.

Comment: See this link for server side parameters https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/